# Why does tabindex here only work with 0 and not the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markup, tabindex

Here is the render method in my React component, which produces the UI in the screenshots below. When I use the app, after selecting the input I have to hit tab twice to select the first coin. However the next tabs start to select different parts of the browser?

```
render() {
  const { coins } = this.state;

  return (
    <section id="search-modal">
      <header className="search-header">
        <input
          id="coin-search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={() => this.handleChange()}
        />
        <button className="close-modal-x" onClick={this.props.closeSquareEdit} />
      </header>
      <ul className="coins-list">
        { coins !== 'undefined'
          ? coins.map((coin, i) => (
            <li
              key={coin.id}
              tabIndex={i}
              onClick={() => this.handleSelect(coin)}
            >
              {coin.name}
              <span className="symbol">({coin.symbol})</span>
            </li>))
          : null
        }
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

^ Here after 2 tabs `Bitcoin` is selected, the 3rd tab seems to reselect the input and the 4th tab click selects the browser url.

Comment: Maybe you have duplicate tabindexes somewhere else on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I needed `role="button"`

```
<ul className="coins-list">
  { coins !== 'undefined'
    ? coins.map((coin, i) => (
      <li
        key={coin.id}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={i}
        onFocus={() => this.setFocus(coin)}
        onClick={() => this.handleSelect(coin)}
      >
        {coin.name}
        <span className="symbol">({coin.symbol})</span>
      </li>))
    : <li>Loading...</li>
  }
</ul>
```

However the strange number of tabs needed to get to the first `li` is still there. I need to hit tab twice... then several more times before it starts to correctly go down the list.

A new function I added and one I modified:

```
setFocus(coin) {
  console.log('setFocus', coin.id);
  this.setState({ focused: coin });
}

handleSelect(coin) {
  console.log('handleSelect', coin.id);
  this.setState({ focused: coin });
  this.props.openEdit(true, coin);
}
```